# Scala regex replace with anonymous function

Tags: regex, scala

In Ruby I can replace characters in a string in the following way:

```
a = "one1two2three"
a.gsub(/\d+/) {|e| e.to_i + 1}
=> "one2two3three"
```

The result of evaluating the block from the second line, will replace what was matched in the pattern. Can we do something equivalent in Scala? Replace something in a regex with the results of a function/anonymous function?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, `Regex#replaceAllIn` has an overloaded version that takes a function `Match => String`. The equivalent Scala version of your code would be:

```
"""\d+""".r.replaceAllIn("one1two2three", m => (m.group(0).toInt + 1).toString)
```