# Is it possible to sort with gsub (anonymous function) like ruby in Scala?

Tags: ruby, regex, scala, functional-programming

Im new in Scala. I need to know if is possible do something like this in Scala:

```
input2.lines.sort_by { |l| l.gsub(/.*?\+(.*?)\+(.*)\n/,"\\2\n").to_i }
```

Please help

Comment: "do something like this" - do what? Please clarify - what are the inputs, what is the expected output...

Comment: IM trying to find out if if possible use sintaxis similar to ruby in scala I see a different question to this for gsub using a block in scala but now I try to know if is possible sort with regex change in scala  this is the link of the another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675820/scala-regex-replace-with-anonymous-function

Comment: Add a "workable" example of your code.

Comment: What does "do something like this" mean? What does "this" do? Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you want to ask [tag:scala] people, you have to phrase the question in a way they understand – this question is only understandable to [tag:ruby] people, who, however, cannot answer your [tag:scala] question.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to sort strings by a sub-section within each string. To do that you first need a regex with a capture group to select the region you're interested in.

```
val re = ".*\\+.*\\+(\\d+)".r
```

Now you can extract and modify what was captured and use the result as the sorting rule.

```
lines.sortBy{case re(n) => n.toInt}
```